# python3 not recognizing the correct python 3 version installed (Centos 7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos

I just installed `python 3.6.8` in Centos via a `sudo yum install python3` command and it got installed successfully. However, when I now do `python3 --version` to check the status, the provided version is 3.6.5.

Do you know why this could be and what I could do to sort it out so that it's reported what's installed, python 3.6.8?

```
[user@project]$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
[user@project]$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
[user@project]$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
[user@project]$ pyenv uninstall 3.6.5
pyenv: version `3.6.5' not installed
```

Comment: What directory was that Python version 3.6.8 installed to?
What do you get when you run `which python3`? 
This issue may be due to how your $PATH is set. Run `echo $PATH` as well and share the output kindly

Comment: I can't believe it. I spent hours on it, left it without explanation and swith the computer off. Now that I try again, it just reports correctly... python3 --version = 3.6.8. No idea what could have happen before... Do you know why this could have been?

I was commenting in the answer below about having python3 appearing in too many places now, one of them seeming a duplicate. Output: https://pastebin.com/gMZZ97EJ

As for the `echo $PATH` command: https://pastebin.com/EacJAqBr

Answer (score 1):

Under some circumstances the shell is messing up the hashing. Alternatively you might have aliases or shell functions overriding python3.

I propose you type following commands to see whether you had a hashing issue or a shell alias or a shell function which overrides python3:

```
type -a python3
which -a python3
hash -r
type -a python3
which -a python3
pyenv which python3
pyenv versions
```

If the output is not self explaining, then post the output of above commands here

Addendum. As you typed pyenv in your question I also added a call to pyenv, though I don't think it's a pyenv issue.

`type -a python3` shows in priority order which commands would be candidates for being found when you type `python3`

shell functions and aliases have priority over commands, that can be found in the path. the path is searched from left to right.

The reason why the last python shows up twice is unclear to me (perhaps you added this directory twice to your search path?)

Comment: I can't believe it. I spent hours on it, left it without explanation and swith the computer off. Now that I try again, it just reports correctly... `python3 --version` = `3.6.8`. No idea what could have happen before... Do you know why this could have been?

As for your commands, it reports 4 different entries (no clue why), even 2 are duplicate :S 
Output: https://pastebin.com/gMZZ97EJ

Comment: Hmmm sometimes I had similar issues in a shell window and rehashing the search path with `hash -r` did the trick

Comment: that's the advantage of type -a it shows the python3 that would be found first, but then it shows the other ones, that were masked by their predecessors